# How can I allow NTLM pass-thru in a Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome-app

Trying to convert an existing web-application to a Chrome app, currently I am at an impass with authenticating to my REST API what expects NTLM/Windows Authentication to provide pass-thru user credentials.

Is there a permission I need to manifest to allow this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the trick was to specify the server itself in the permissions of the manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "http://localhost/*"
]
```